# My call doesn't end when I pass the option IfMachine=>Hangup

Tags: twilio

Here is my code:

```
$options = array('StatusCallback'=>'http://myserver.com/twilioStatusCallback.php','IfMachine'=>'Hangup');
$call = $client->account->calls->create ($phonenumber, 'xxxxxx6016', $url, $options);
```

The status callback works, but Twilio continues to go on and leave a message for the answering machine. What I want is for it to hangup when a machine answers and continue if it is a human.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answering machine detection feature is currently marked as experimental on the Twilio Documentation (http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls#handling-outcomes-answering-machines).

If this is happening on every call you make that ends in an answer phone i'd get in touch with Twilio support - help@twilio.com